# Convert LaTeX to SymPy format

Tags: luatex, python

I'm trying to convert LaTeX to SymPy understandable format and I feel it's hard to comply all conditions. So Im wondering if you can suggest any tools, free or paid, that will be great.

What I'm looking for is:

- `\frac{1}{3x^{2} + 13x - 10}` to `(1)/((3*x)**2+13*x-10)`
- `\lim_{x\to a}\frac{x}{y}` to `limit(x/y,x,a)`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Nice rhyme in the end. It should be mandatory to do so on this site :)

Comment: Are fractions and limites the only thing you want to convert?

Comment: No, I want Integration, Derivatives, Trigonometric etc. Thanks @Ruben

Comment: Due to the variations in notation, this may be prohibitively difficult. For example, what do I mean by `\sum_{i \to 5} i^{-2} \sum_{b \to 10} b`? How would you write that in Python? (You as a human are certainly more intelligent than any algorithm – especially for such a simple example.)

Comment: There is an open feature request for adding such a feature to `sympy`: https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/5418

Comment: @SeanAllred Yes I do understand that but if I find any tool doing some what near what i want, then i can add/change logic to suit my requirements

Comment: This is like 5 years project for 5 people to do right. You are basically asking for a compiler. Translating  one language to another.

Comment: I think you severely underestimate the complexities involved here…

Comment: Since TeX is a macro expansion language the input parsing is not possible. Hence one needs to check the output and recognize it what it might mean. Instead you can write simple regex so that it grabs the \frac arguments and put brackets around them with a `/` in between etc. But it will always be a hack not a tool.

Comment: @percusse yes my approach is to write regex classes for different math equations.

Comment: @jagannath What do you mean by *yes*? I tried to mention that this is a lost cause. You can only fix your specific case in your own document.

Comment: If you are fluent with grammar specification languages such as yacc, and the expressions you are trying to convert do not depend on new macros being defined "on the fly", perhaps you can use `parsley` to write a python parser for your expressions, instead of regexp which will be surely much more difficult to write and maintain.

Comment: Using regex to solve a problem will give you a second problem by the end of the day. `:)`

Answer (score 4):

Here's a parser that does the job for a big subset of Latex:

https://github.com/augustt198/latex2sympy

Comment: Could you comment more on what can and cannot do?

Answer (score 3):

[This](https://algorithmia.com/algorithms/Jeffro/LatexLambda) might help. It converts LaTeX notation to Lambda string of which you could use with `eval()`in python to use the function.

Comment: Please don't post link-only answers. Include the relevant details of the link inside your post so make the answer self-contained (even if it is only screen-shots of its usage), and include the link as reference. Moreover, add some disclosure that you're the author of the conversion function...