# pgfplot latex expression as input

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pdftex

I would like to feed input to the pgfPlot in pure latex format. For example not like `sqrt(x-1) -2*x` but    `\sqrt(x-1) -2x`. It is because I am generating plots automatically with given latex input. Thus not hand coded. Is there a way to do that? Or at least how can I convert latex input to the one pgfPlots expects(asciimath?) ?
Thank you.

Comment: Welcome! "Is there a way to do that?" Unfortunately not really. Even if one ignores the fact that `\sqrt(x-1) -2x` isn't proper LaTeX input (you probably meant `\sqrt{x-1} -2x`) it will not be really feasible to write a parser that deals with all the possible LaTeX input in a robust way.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX ! Depending on the programming language you are using, some parsers may already exist. [Here is a similar question for python.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/256644/convert-latex-to-sympy-format)

Comment: Yes, I am already using it for converting to symp. However, pgfplot does not accept symyp input neither. (I am also using sympy's plotting functionality, didn't like it, I want to use pgfplot)

Comment: If you already use `python`, one could yhink of `matplotlib2tikz` to convert plots from `python` to `pgfplots` but I don't think it parses expressions (though I did not check). Otherwise, if you know your `pyrhon` and your expressions are not that complex, you could write your own parser, but it would require some effort and time.